# How can I send APDU to SIM card in android applications?

Tags: android, sim-card, apdu

I know about the SEEK solution, but it does not fit my req.
I know there are some internal APIs that can do some, but it limits the functions.I need to send evenlope APDU to SIM and get the response.
thanks!

Comment: What *does* fit your requirements? I would say I'm very familiar with this topic, but it is very OEM specific.

Comment: you try to see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361764/how-to-store-android-application-data-on-sim-card-using-nfc

Comment: Could you do it? Had any success in this issue? I appreciate if share your experience and knowledge with me :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to send Envelope command, you need access to the basic channel on the card. Not all phone's modems will allow this, and if yours does, you still need to have a system permission granted to be allowed to do this through the RIL. So it is unlikely you succeed, and even then your solution won't scale.