# How to use android smart card api for secure element

Tags: android, security, nfc, smartcard, apdu

I am developing an android application and I want to store my data securely.
There are two way for that

1. Storing Sim card
2. [Mobile security card](https://www.cardsolutions-shop.com/shop/gi-de/)

I want to use second one but I don't want to buy this card before I make sure it is useful for me.

I am running Google's `SmartcardSample`([svn](http://seek-for-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk)) application.
But I get an error like this.

[image: java error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer for using the SIM as Secure Element https://stackoverflow.com/a/9364030/156477 (Its not scalable solution at present).

This isn't Google's code, and the SEEK API isn't part of Android (out of the box). Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/wiki/SmartcardAPI. You'll see at the bottom you need to rebuild your own version of the Android OS, and flash it to your device.

I notice you haven't tagged the question with NFC.  I wonder, do you really need SmartCard support or do you just need to store data securely?  The typical SmartCard use case is to use the phone for payment, or building access - know as NFC Card Emulation mode.

Comment: i need to use as tag my phone(NFC Card Emulation mode). And i know , i need to mobile phone which support nfc.

Comment: i am using Turkcell T11 and this phone support NFC and it contains the SmartCard Service but i didnt use this service i get the error which in my question. Whaat is the reason? signature or permission? but i also add permissions in manifest file.

Comment: Your problem is that *you* don't have authority to access the SE. The root TSM has authority and would need to give you certificate keys to let you access the secure element. Turkcell is the root TSM in this case. It is very unlikely that they will give access to anyone except the largest enterprises. If they start giving access to any 3rd party developer who wants it, then it is no longer secure.